# Using int[] arrays to manipulate each other through nested loops

Tags: java, arrays

What I am trying to do is use one method to generate 30 random numbers from 0-15 and then another method to count how many times each number prints and put it in a second array. Each position in the second array corresponds to the number in the array it is. if i = [0] and 0 shows up 3 times, it should be 3 and so on.

So far, I have gotten this. What seems to be happening is that it counts the number of times 15 shows up (The last number of the array). Though I could be wrong. I don't see what I'm doing wrong. There must be something wrong with my logic.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FrequencyOfNumbers {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomNums()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedNums(randomNums())));
    }

    public static int[] randomNums (){
        int[] random = new int[30];
        for(int i=0;i<random.length;i++){
           double randNum = Math.random() * 16;
            random[i] = (int)randNum;
        }
        return random;
    }

    public static int[] sortedNums(int[] sort){
        int[] numVals = new int[15];
        for(int i=0;i<numVals.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<sort.length;j++)
            {
                if(sort[j] == numVals[i])
                {
                    numVals[i]++;
                }
            }
        }
        return numVals;
    }
}
```

Example output I'm receiving:

```
[5, 15, 0, 5, 4, 10, 4, 11, 5, 13, 13, 8, 9, 9, 10, 6, 0, 9, 10, 12, 3, 7, 4, 9, 4, 11, 9, 15, 10, 7]

[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Since `numVals` is initialized to 15 zeroes, what do you expect `if(sort[j] == numVals[i])` to do? Perhaps you just wanted the inner loop and do `numVals[sort[j]]++;`?

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: Actually this helped me but what I actually wanted was if(sort[j] = i)

Comment: @KylianMurphy but did you try the answer? using a nested for is less advisable if `Collections` can do is (From my experience)

Comment: I solved it. So should I delete this or change my question to an answer? I don't know the protocol

Comment: @KylianMurphy I think you should leave it... but please look at the answer. I think using the Collections is more advisable

Comment: Yeah, I tried changing numVals[i]++ to numVals[sort[j]]++ but it wasn't producing the output I was expecting. The numbers at the start of the array were big (like 25, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0)

But I figured out that it was actually i that I was comparing the number to and not numVals[i]

Comment: @KylianMurphy - I can't understand the use of nested for when there's a much better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problems in the code:

1. Don't call `randomNums()` twice. Otherwise you don't count the right frequency. It will generate different arrays.
2. If you want to keep numbers from 0 to 15, you should allocate 16 elements for `numVals`.
3. You don't need an inner `for` loop when you count the appearances. Just consider all the numbers, take their values, and increment the number of appearances.

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] randomNumbers = randomNums();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomNumbers));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedNums(randomNumbers)));
}

public static int[] randomNums() {
    int[] random = new int[30];
    for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
        random[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 16);
    }
    return random;
}

public static int[] sortedNums(int[] sort) {
    int[] numVals = new int[16];
    for (int j = 0; j < sort.length; j++) {
        numVals[sort[j]]++;
    }
    return numVals;
}
```

A possible output:

```
[8, 6, 5, 12, 12, 9, 15, 6, 7, 9, 15, 3, 6, 7, 3, 8, 6, 3, 15, 8, 12, 4, 7, 12, 2, 15, 6, 5, 4, 5]
[0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 4]
```

---

**Performance**

If you want to count the number of comparisons (practically) you can:

1. Create a new member in your class:

   ```
   static int steps = 0;
   ```
2. Define a new method that increments the counter:

   ```
   private static boolean f() {
       steps++;
       return true;
   }
   ```
3. Add `f() &&` before the current condition in `if`.
4. Add the following last line in the `main` method:

   ```
   System.out.println(steps);
   ```

Using only one `for` you will generate `30` steps.

Using 2 `for` loops (as you wrote in your comment) will generate `480` steps (`480 = 30 * 16`).

In this case is irrelevant because both operations are very fast. But for a larger input if the first approach takes 1 second, you should care if the second one takes more than 10 seconds.

Comment: I am using     `public static int[] sortedNums(int[] sort){
        int[] numVals = new int[16];
        for(int i=0;i<numVals.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<sort.length;j++)
            {
                if(sort[j] == i)
                {
                    numVals[i]++;
                }
            }
        }
        return numVals;
    }
}`

Comment: It seems to work the same way. Can you confirm or deny this for learning purposes? I have changed the array call in the Main method as well

Comment: Yes. This solution is also correct. Probably it's more intuitive for you, but it's not so fast as mine. However, for such a small input (30 numbers) you won't see any difference in performance.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I can see what you mean, it's less typing and so on. I am not worried about performance differences right now, but I will try to alter my style to incorporate this.

Comment: Perfect. I added some details about the performance to have a better understanding about those differences.

Answer (score 3):

To count the number of instances of an object in a collection you can use `Collections.frequency()`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < sort.length; i++) {
    list.add(sort[i]);
}

for(int i = 0; i< numVals.length;i++){
    numVals[i] = Collections.frequency(list, i);
}
return numVals;
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but I am not using ArrayLists in this particular exercise.

Comment: @KylianMurphy if you find the answer useful, you can upvote it

Comment: Yes, I would. But somebody went through the effort of spamming all my questions with negative feedback when I posted this question and I no longer have the ability to do so.

Comment: @kylian Murphy, now that's just mean.

Comment: Not sure if it was you who actually went through and gave me all +'s but anyways, I upvoted you now :)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I think somebody went through and gave me positive feedback to all my stuff after I posted to you that somebody went and posted negative on all my stuff. Either way, I can rate stuff again! So I gave you a feedback!